# Libraries used to create antivirus in Python

Tags: library, python, antivirus

So, I just want to create an antivirus with Python. Are there any libraries that could help me achieve this? It simply should warn the user if there is a malware and remove it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: edited please check

Comment: Do you mean a library with just a IsMalware(file) method that return true if the file is malware? Should it work offline, or can it rely on a web service? Should it be gratis? Open source?

Comment: it should work offline. open source (Unlicence preferred). and yes it should be `IsMalware`...